# Folding a list in OCaml

Tags: recursion, ocaml, fold

In OCaml, a typical fold function looks like this:

```
let rec fold (combine: 'a -> 'b -> 'b) (base: 'b) (l: 'a list) : 'b =
  begin match l with
  | [] -> base
  | x :: xs -> combine x (fold combine base xs)
  end
```

For those familiar with OCaml (unlike me), it should be pretty straightforward what it's doing.

I'm writing a function that returns true when all items in the list satisfy the condition: if condition x is true for all x in some list l. However I'm implementing the function using a fold function and I'm stuck. Specifically I don't know what the list should return. I know that ideally the condition should be applied to every item in the list but I have no idea how the syntax should look. `x && acc` works but it fails a very simply test (shown below)

```
let test () : bool =
  not (for_all (fun x -> x > 0) [1; 2; -5; -33; 2])
;; run_test "for_all: multiple elements; returns false" test
```

Here is my preliminary attempt. Any help is appreciated:

```
let  for_all (pred: 'a -> bool) (l: 'a list) : bool =
fold (fun(x:'a)(acc: bool)->  _?_&&_?_  )false l
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let rec fold (combine: 'a -> 'b -> 'b) (base: 'b) (l: 'a list) : 'b =
  match l with
  | [] -> base
  | x::xs -> combine x (fold combine base xs)

let for_all (pred: 'a -> bool) (lst: 'a list) =
  let combine x accum =
    (pred x) && accum
  in
  fold combine true lst
```

Your combine function should not do `x && base` because elements of the list are not usually `bool`. You want your predicate function first evaluate the element to bool, then you "and" it with the accumulator.

There is no need for `begin` and `end` in `fold`. You can just pattern match with `match <identifier> with`.

There are two widespread types of `fold`: `fold_left` and `fold_right`. You're are using `fold_right`, which, basically, goes through the whole list and begins "combining" from the end of the list to the front. This is not [tail-recursive](https://abitofocaml.weebly.com/131-tail-recursion.html).

`fold_left`, on the other hand goes from the front of the list and combines every element with the accumulator right away. This does not "eat up" your stack by a number of recursive function calls.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fold` works fine.

But you are operating under a faulty premise about how `for_all` should work. You start with your initial value on `false`, but `for_all` is checking that a condition holds true for every element. It only needs to find *one* element for which that doesn't hold true to know that the entire thing is false.

On each iterative call, if the accumulator is already `false` we know we can just propagate that to the end of the fold. If it's true, we update the accumulator to the result of calling the predicate on the current value.

```
let for_all predicate lt =
  fold (fun x acc -> if not acc then acc else predicate x) true lst
```

This is an inherently inefficient way to implement `for_all` because even if the very first iteration returns `false` we still have to traverse the entire list.

By writing this without `fold` we can exit the recursion as soon as the `false` condition is found.

```
let rec for_all predicate = function
  | [] -> true
  | x::_ when not (predicate x) -> false
  | _::xs -> for_all predicate xs
```